# How to skip whitespaces but not the newline

Tags: c++, iostream

I want skip all `SP`s and `HT`s from a `std::istream`, then read a string from it up to the first `SP` or `HT`, then skip all `SP`s and `HT`s, and then read everything up to the newline `\n`.

I tried

```
stream >> str >> std::ws;
std::getline(stream, rest);
```

but doesn't quite work, because `std::ws` eats newlines as well as spaces and horizontal tabulation. I guess I can do

```
stream >> str;
std::getline(stream, rest);
trim_leading_whitespace(rest);
```

or even `std::getline(stream, temp); do_regex_match("/* some complex regex */", temp, str, rest);`.

Is it possible to somehow fix the first attempt using only `iostream`-related stuff? It personally looks most concise, though of course any advices how to write it shortly and clearly are welcome.

Comment: Is this of help? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: @AdriC.S. `ignore` ignores only one specific character. Of course, I could devise something like `while(stream.ignore(1, '\x20') || stream.ignore(1, '\t'));`... actually, let me check this.

Comment: But, if instead of `count = 1` you have `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`, shouldn't it discard all whitespaces?

Comment: Wouldn't this work stream >> str >> someChar;
std::getline(stream, rest); rest2 = someChar + rest;

Comment: @AdriC.S. No, `ignore` skips everything until the first `delim`-character.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an extra stream, on the read line:

```
std::string data; // <<-- trimmed data
std::string line;
std::getline(stream, line);
std::istringstream line_buffer(line);
line_buffer >> std::ws >> data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own facet that registers user-supplied whitespace characters to the underlying table. Creating manipulators for enabling/disabling this feature is an exercise I'll leave to you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class ctype : public std::ctype<char>
{
    template<class... Args>
    static mask* make_table(Args... args)
    {
       static std::vector<mask> table(classic_table(),
                                      classic_table() + table_size);
       typedef int pack[];

       (void)pack{ ((table[args] |= space), void(), 0) ... };
       table['\n'] &= ~space;

       return &v[0];
    }
public:
    template<class... Args>
    ctype(Args... args)
        : std::ctype<char>(make_table(args...)) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("!@#abc");
    iss.imbue(std::locale(iss.getloc(), new ctype('!', '@', '#')));
    std::string str;

    std::getline(iss >> std::ws, str);
    std::cout << str; // "abc"
}
```